# setTimeout function in saga React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga, saga

I just want to hide Undo Button in UI after 5 seconds. Here is my code:

Saga.js

```js
function* updateActionListingsSaga({ payload }) {
  try {
    const res = yield call(updateUnpublishedListingsById, payload);
    let unpublishedListings = yield select(UnpublishedListings);
    if (res) {
      const row = unpublishedListings.listingsData.results.find(data => data.id === res.ids[0])
      if (row) {
        row.review_status = payload.review_status
        row.isUndoEnabled = true;
        yield setTimeout(() => {row.isUndoEnabled = false}, 5000)
      }
    }
    
    yield put(updateActionListingSuccess());
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(apiError(error.error || error.message || error));
  }
}
```

Index.js

```js
item?.isUndoEnabled && (
  <ConfirmDialogBtn
    button={{
      color: 'primary',
      title: 'Undo',
      icon: 'bx bx-undo',
    }}
    msg="Set this Listing as Undo"
    onConfirm={() => handleUpdateListing(item?.id, 'pending')}
  />
)
```

I am retrieving a particular row set an Undo Button by appending `row.isUndoEnabled= true` property and After 5 seconds delay I just set it to `row.isUndoEnabled= false`.

Actual Output: Property is set to True but doesn't hide the Button

Expected Output: Hide the Button

Hope for the best Answer.
Thank you

Comment: "Actual Output: Property is set to True but doesn't hide the Button" so where do you hide the button?

Comment: @DennisVash Inside the UI I put a condition when isUndoEnabled is true then it will show otherwise it will be hidden

Comment: The problem is that yield put(updateActionListingSuccess()); run before timeout callback function. I Recommend you to put some action inside timeout, and that action update row.isUndoEnabled value

Comment: @lissettdm Exactly you are right. What type of action I have to put?

Comment: Well you need to create a new action for this case, or try to call updateActionListingSuccess() again

Comment: @lissettdm I have also tried this but does not work.

Comment: What did you try? please, update your answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226097/discussion-between-hassam-saeed-and-lissettdm).

Comment: You shouldn't modify the state directly, but use action + reducer

Comment: @AlekseyL. Thanks for your comment. I found the solution which is provided by lissettdm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The button is not hiding because `updateActionListingSuccess` function is called before timeout callback is executed. I recommend you:

1. Wrap the `timeout` function inside a `Promise` and wait until it finished.
2. Call `updateActionListingSuccess` just after the promise is resolved.

```js
    function* updateActionListingsSaga({ payload }) {
      try {
        const res = yield call(updateUnpublishedListingsById, payload);
        let unpublishedListings = yield select(UnpublishedListings);
        let row = null;
        if (res) {
          row = unpublishedListings.listingsData.results.find(
            data => data.id === res.ids[0]
          );
          if (row) {
            row.review_status = payload.review_status;
            row.isUndoEnabled = true;
          }
        }
        yield put(updateActionListingSuccess());
        if (row) {
          yield new Promise(resolve =>
            setTimeout(() => {
              row.isUndoEnabled = false;
              resolve();
            }, 5000)
          );
        }
        yield put(updateActionListingSuccess()); // update again
      } catch (error) {
        yield put(apiError(error.error || error.message || error));
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @lissettdm